# Accessing variable inside a static function class

Tags: php, oop

I have a login.php and authenticate.php

I want to access a variable inside the authenticate.php inside a class.
I want to get the error message from authenticate class to my login.php

This is my class inside Authenticate.php

```
Class Authenticate {

    public $invalidUserErrMsg = "sdfs";

    static public function LDAPAuthenticate() {
                 //connection stuff
            } else {
                $msg = "Invalid username / password";
                $this->invalidUserErrMsg = $msg;

            }
    }

    static public function invalidUserErr() {
        echo $hits->invalidUserErrMsg;
        return $this->invalidUserErrMsg;
    }

}
```

This is how I'm printing inside login.php

```
<?php 
    $error = new Authenticate();
    $error->invalidUserErr(); 
?>
```

Comment: You're returning the value from `invalidUserErr()` so just assign that when you call it in your login

Comment: use `$error = new Authenticate::invalidUserErr();`

Comment: you get an error because there is not if() within the LDAPAuthenticate()

Comment: @Lars There's a condition inside that function, and the message si returning within the class, I just want to position the error message properly cause its showing on the top of the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Class Authenticate {

    public $invalidUserErrMsg = "sdfs";

    public function LDAPAuthenticate() {
        if($hello) {
             echo 'hello';
        } else {
            $msg = "Invalid username / password";
            $this->invalidUserErrMsg = $msg;

        }
}

   public function invalidUserErr() {
        return $this->invalidUserErrMsg;
    }

}

<?php 
    $error = new Authenticate();
    echo $error->invalidUserErr(); 
?>
```

Don't echo the variable within the class but echo the method on login.php. There is no need to make it a static function if you are going to instantiate the object anyway.

Check out [this](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php) page on the static keyword

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Authenticate::invalidUserErr()

Comment: That is because you declared the function as static

Comment: Just tested the code 'as is' in my answer and it works

Comment: didn't see the echo part! thnaks!

Comment: No worries, Good luck ;)

Comment: sorry, its printing the initialized value from the class authenticate, any idea about this?

Comment: now its returning, Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Using $this when not in object context in

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100459/discussion-between-lars-and-suisied).

Answer (score 0):

For accessing static function you need

```
<?php 
  $error = new Authenticate::invalidUserErr();

?>
```